# KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /admin/preferred_replica_election

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

when i starting kafka,zookeeper happens error.

```
INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x156028651c00001 type:delete cxid:0x1b zxid:0x59 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/admin/preferred_replica_election Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /admin/preferred_replica_election (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
```

Comment: A similar question (tl;dr it's not an error, just an info log) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43559328/got-user-level-keeperexception-when-processing

Answer (score 6):

Please be informed that this is not an error it is just a log warning on zookeeper .Howeaver the `kafka-producer` will not be able to produce messages to the topic on the first go.But will be on the subsequent trials.......while using a `kafka-node` library.

Answer (score 5):

Are you running on single node with replication 1? Then it should not bother you. You can read more about it here https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Replication+tools

Exceptions can also be seen for znode path **/brokers/ids** or **/brokers** because they are not present(on zookeeper) initially when you start the kafka-server.